# How to append the data in big query having a column mode as REQUIRED in python? Error I get is ABC_Col changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE

Tags: sql, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

```
value = self.bq_client.import_data_from_dataframe(table=table_id, dataframe=dataframe,
                                          source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
                                          autodetect=True,
                                          write_disposition=operation_type,
                                          allow_quoted_newlines=True)
```

The code I am using right now is the above but it throws an exception as I mentioned when I try to append data into my BQ table. There are no nulls in the data to be appended.

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't an empty line at the end of the file? Is it an option for you to add the schema instead of using autodetect? And Are you sure that you haven't null/empty data for this column?

Comment: No @guillaumeblaquiere, I don't have an option to add the schema. And yes, I don't have any null/empty data.

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't an empty line at the end of the file? Sorry. I didn't get this. What does this mean?